# how to compress a files inside a shell script file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, compression, terminal

I have seen a .sh file on execution in terminal it extracts some jar files inside the sh file, how to create such sh files? i could not open that sh file in normal gedit to check the content.
 Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410785/bash-script-containing-binary-executable

Comment: The trick to a self extracting shell file is to simply create a normal archive using standard tools such as `tar` (or zip, cpio etc.) and then wrap the resulting `.tar` file in a couple lines of shell script that will separate out the archive from the script, extract it again and execute any additional setup steps. Decoding that should be trivial, but an editor attempting to do syntax highlighting or matching braces on the binary contents of such a file might be quite slow. Try `/bin/vi` instead of `gedit`.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of *shar* for shell archives? See `man shar` for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use *shar* for Shell Archives

Create shell archives using the [*shar* utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/). For example:

```
# Create some fixture data to archive.
cd /tmp
mkdir -p foo/bar/baz
touch foo/bar/baz/quux

# Create the shell archive.
find foo/ -exec shar {} + > quux.sh

# Remove fixture data.
rm -rf foo/

# Extract archive to recreate directories and files.
sh quux.sh
```

You can validate that this recreated your data with `ls -R foo`. In addition, if you inspect *quux.sh*, you'll see that it's composed of a series of simple shell commands. You can insert those commands directly into another shell script, if desired, or call the archive from another script to unpack it.

### Caveats

The BSD version of *shar* on macOS doesn't handle binary data without a separate encoding step, while the GNU version has various [encoding options](https://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/manual/html_node/shar-encoding.html#shar-encoding) available to it. If your version of shar doesn't handle binary encoding, you may be better off with a more robust archiving option like *tar*. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -4):

To compress a file or set of files you can use the `gzip` command in UNIX.

To zip a single file use:-

```
$ gzip filename
```

It will create a file named `filename.gz`.
To zip a folder, first create a `.tar` file and then zip it.
Let the name of the folder be `shell`.

To create a `.tar` file use:-

```
$ tar cvf filename.tar shell/.
```

It will create a file named `filename.tar`

Now use

```
$ gzip filename.tar
```

It will create a file named `filename.tar.gz`.
So in this way you can compress a file.

Note: To uncompress a file you can use `gunzip` command.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question.

Comment: that was not the answer to my question